# How to save server response which is in xml format into String variable in android?

Tags: android

I have an app in which I have to send String request to server and server is sending me response in xml format.How can I read this response ans save it in String variable and convert into json.

server is reponding reponse like:-

```
<Response>
<st-code>0</st-code>
<st-desc>Transaction Successful</st-desc>
<st-no>XXXXXX</st-no>
<st-tno>111111</st-tno>
<st-optno>XXXXXXXXX</st-optno>
```

Comment: Try googling before asking a question next time

Answer (score 0):

- Download the following library
  [java-json](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/java/java-json.jar.zip)
- Add this library to `/libs` of your project
- Now Import the required libraries 
  `import org.json.JSONException;`
  `import org.json.JSONObject;`
  `import org.json.XML;`
- Now use the following code to convert your xml string to json

  ```
  sampleXml = "";//XML string to convert it to JSON
  JSONObject jsonObj = null;
  try 
  {
      jsonObj = XML.toJSONObject(sampleXml);
  } 
  catch (JSONException e) 
  {
      Log.e("JSON exception", e.getMessage());
      e.printStackTrace();
  } 

  Log.d("XML", sampleXml);

  Log.d("JSON", jsonObj.toString());
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Using foll. code snippet :

```
JSONObject xmlToJson = XML.toJSONObject(YOUR_XML_STRING);
String jsonString = xmlToJson.toString(ANY_INTEGER_VALUE);
```

Comment: what is XML. in your answer

Comment: XML is class, Check this - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Xml.html